# Memory Management (OOM) : java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing an application where my main page is a grid view where I fetch thumbnail images from the server. When a user clicks on an image on the main activity, it gets position of the item and call another url to load a single fullsize image and loading into the detail activity. I have just go back and forward between main and detail activity by using back button. I have done this step 8-9 times and my app crashes, it throws out of memory (OOM).

My full size images vary between 30 kb to 115 kb. Thumbnail images vary 20 kb to 45 kb.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()

I am using Volley and my image load as follows in the detail activity.

In the following code, I retrieve clicked product json object, it contains an URL of corresponding full-size image.

**Retrieve Detail Product JSON object in the Main Activity.**

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.PRODUCT_DETAIL_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductDetailActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("jsonArray", response);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", productid);
                return params;
            }
     }
```

I send the JSON object as follows `intent.putExtra("jsonArray", response);` from Main Activity to the Detail Activity and fetch the image URL and display it in the ImageView as follows.

**In the DetailActivity**

```
 String MY_URL_STRING = Config.IMAGE_PATH_URL+"/"+obj.optString("pimagePath");
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detailImage))
                .execute(MY_URL_STRING);
```

**DownloadImageTask Class**

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**CustomVolley Request**

```
private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }

}
```

I tested the app while I was monitoring the memory and I observed that memory is allocated and never released back even though I am not looking at that image anymore. It keeps incrementing. Sorry, I am coming from iOS side, relatively new to Android and do not understand memory management.

Memory Monitoring, each click increments, it does free the memory when I go back to main activity!

[image]

Stack Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask  E/AndroidRuntime: 
Process: PID: 5700 
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
doInBackground()  E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)  E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:613)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:589)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:627)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 com.example.xxx.xxx.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:26)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 com.example.xxx.xxx.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:14)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: DownloadImageTask code? are you holding any resources there ?

Comment: I have added `DownloadImageTask` class, please see my updated question

Comment: can you try using Picasso once?
Not many changes.
add this in gradle file
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Wherever you are using this downloadAsyncTask to fetch and load
Picasso.with(your_context).load(your_img_url).into(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW);

Comment: I have used volley networkImageView but it slightly improves memory issue but still after number of clicks still crashes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751810/java-lang-runtimeexception-canvas-trying-to-use-a-recycled-bitmap